# How did the meaning of "once more, anew" arise in "again"?

Tags: etymology

Ayto doesn't expound where the late 14c. meaning of ‘once more, anew’ sprang from?  Is "once more, anew"  related to "in a direct line with, facing" or "in the opposite direction, back"?

> #### again [OE]

> The underlying etymological sense
> of *again* is ‘in a direct line with, facing’, hence
> ‘opposite’ and ‘in the opposite direction, back’
> (its original meaning in Old English). It comes
> from a probable Germanic **gagin* ‘straight’,
> which was the source of many compounds
> formed with *on* or *in* in various Germanic
> languages, such as Old Saxon *angegin* and Old
> Norse *íg gegn*. The Old English form was
> *ongēan*, which would have produced *ayen* in
> modern English; however, Norse-influenced
> forms with a hard *g* had spread over the whole
> country from northern areas by the 16th century.
> **The meaning ‘once more, anew’ did not develop
> until the late 14th century.** From Old English
> times until the late 16th century a prefix-less
> form *gain* was used in forming compounds. It
> carried a range of meanings, from ‘against’ to ‘in
> return’, but today survives only in *gainsay*.
>       The notion of ‘opposition’ is carried through
> in *against*, which was formed in the 12th century
> from again and what was originally the genitive
> suffix *-es*, as in *always* and *nowadays*. The
> parasitic *-t* first appeared in the 14th century.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 11 Right column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Again** was originally used as both a preposition and an adjective

OED:

> A. adv. I. Expressing reversal or reciprocation. **1.†a. In the opposite direction; back. *Obsolete*.**
>
> OE   Battle of Maldon (1942) 137   *He sceaf þa mid ðam scylde, þæt se sceaft tobærst, and þæt spere sprengde, þæt hit sprang ongean.* – [(so) that it sprang back]

Thus indicating a repetition or a return to a former state, thus anew; as before.

> **B. prep. Now regional and nonstandard, esp. in forms agen, agin, agin', etc. In Old English with accusative or dative.**
>
> **I. Expressing position or motion towards or facing something.**
>
> **1. a. In a direction contrary to or facing; towards, in the direction of, forward to, so as to meet; = against prep. 1b.**
>
> eOE   Anglo-Saxon Chron. (Parker) anno 893   *Þa hie gefengon micle herehyð & þa woldon ferian norþweardes ofer Temese in on Eastseaxe **ongean þa scipu***. [Against, i.e. opposite to, the ships]
>
> 1996   S. Moylan Lang. Kilkenny i. 15   *I seen this thing comin' again me in the hollow o' the road.*

The word “**against**” has the same origins as **again** but around the 14th century, they separated, with **against** being the preposition and **again** being the adverb, with their respective meanings.